# Проблема с сохранением переносов строк в YAML при использовании функции yaml.dump в Python

Tags: python

Занимаюсь локализацией YAML-файла, содержащего строки с переносами. При использовании функции yaml.dump для записи обновленных переводов обратно в файл, столкнулся с проблемой, что строки с переносами сохраняются в одну длинную строку, что делает файл трудным для чтения.

Пример строки до перевода:

```yaml
'Select the country where you want your content to rank. This is crucial for tailoring your SEO strategy to specific regions.': '__Select the country where you want your content to rank. This is crucial for tailoring your SEO strategy to specific regions.'
```

Что получается после перевода:

```yaml
? Select the country where you want your content to rank. This is crucial for tailoring
  your SEO strategy to specific regions.
: Выберите страну, в которой вы хотите, чтобы ваш контент был ранжирован. Это критически
  важно для адаптации вашей SEO-стратегии к конкретным регионам.
```

Код, что я использую для записи переводов обратно в yaml файл:

```py
with open(yaml_path, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(translations_yaml, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

Использую библиотеку PyYAML в Python и пробовал различные комбинации стилей блока (|, >, +), но проблема не решается. Что я делаю неправильно? Как можно корректно сохранить переносы строк в YAML?

Comment: Приведите конкретный примеры фрагмента исходного файла, кода как вы его читаете, кода как записываете, полученного фрагмента.